# Unity3D C#: OnTriggerEnter setting to only one tag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was creating a simple scene in Unity3D today where a player would choose their colour by colliding into a wall, which would change the tag of the player to 'RedPlayer', 'BluePlayer', etc; And print on the Debug Log saying 'He's a red boy!', or whatever the player chose. However, everything thing was working fine until I added the last wall in (WhitePlayer), and every wall changed the Player's tag to WhitePlayer, however it still prints the colour of the wall they collide with.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class ColourChoice : MonoBehaviour
{

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "RedCollision")
            Debug.Log("He's a Red Boy!");
        gameObject.tag = "RedPlayer";

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "YellowCollision")
            Debug.Log("He's a Yellow Boy!");
        gameObject.tag = "YellowPlayer";

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "BlueCollision")
            Debug.Log("He's a Blue Boy!");
        gameObject.tag = "BluePlayer";

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "GreyCollision")
            Debug.Log("He's a Grey Boy!");
        gameObject.tag = "GreyPlayer";

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "GreenCollision")
            Debug.Log("He's a Green Boy!");
        gameObject.tag = "GreenPlayer";

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "MaroneCollision")
            Debug.Log("He's a Marone Boy!");
        gameObject.tag = "MaronePlayer";

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "PurpleCollision")
            Debug.Log("He's a Purple Boy!");
        gameObject.tag = "PurplePlayer";

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "OrangeCollision")
            Debug.Log("He's a Orange Boy!");
        gameObject.tag = "OrangePlayer";

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "WhiteCollision")
            Debug.Log("He's a White Boy!");
        gameObject.tag = "WhitePlayer";
    }
}
```

I've included the code here, hoping someone can figure it out. If I could get an explanation on how to fix this, that would be great.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was already bad before you added the `WhiteCollision` tag check. This is a typical mistake by new programmers.

Without the open and closing braces  after each `if` statement, the `Debug.Log` will only run if the `if` statement is `true`. Other code under the Debug.Log will execute regardless of if the if statement on top of it is true or not.

You must put the `if` statement code that will execute if something is `true` in a curly braces `{}` if you want multiple lines of code to execute.

So

```
   if (other.gameObject.tag == "RedCollision")
   Debug.Log("He's a Red Boy!");
   gameObject.tag = "RedPlayer";
```

should be

```
if (other.gameObject.tag == "RedCollision"){
    Debug.Log("He's a Red Boy!");
    gameObject.tag = "RedPlayer";
}
```

Do this for each of the if statements in your code.

Tom improve your code, use `if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("RedCollision"))` to compare `tags`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have braces (`{}`) for your `if`'s.
The last line of code that runs in `OnTriggerEnter` function is `gameObject.tag = "WhitePlayer";`

Answer (score 0):

As incredibly clean as it is, you can't write two lines of code in a "short statement" `if`

Notice you do not have `{}` enclosing the *two lined* `then`? Ya you can't do that. Short hand or short statement is for one line and one line only. Being fancy is fine most of the time but is *incredibly* wasteful if you get an error and don't enclose it in a "proper" if statement when debugging these errors.

To answer your question, change:

```
if (other.gameObject.tag == "RedCollision")
  Debug.Log("He's a Red Boy!");
    gameObject.tag = "RedPlayer";
```

To:

```
if (other.gameObject.tag == "RedCollision") {
    Debug.Log("He's a Red Boy!");
    gameObject.tag = "RedPlayer";
}
```

And ALWAYS properly indent your stuff if you ever mess with short hand.

Do a test on this:

```
if( X != 1 )
    Debug.Log( "1" );
    if( X == 2 )
        Debug.Log( "2" );
    else
        Debug.Log( "3" );
```

And:

```
if( X != 1 )
    Debug.Log( "1" );
    if( X == 2 )
        Debug.Log( "2" );
   else
        Debug.Log( "3" );
```

Notice the *one space difference*

Thanks to this Python-ian indent type, if your `X` is equal to two, the top example will log `"1"` then `"2"` whereas the bottom will log `"3"`